# How do I recode year values for growth curve?--a better way

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

So I know that if I had 15 years 2003:2017, and I wanted to change those years to be 0:15, I could individually code them `` dat =  dat%>%mutate(year.start = recode(year, `2003` = 0, `2004` = 1, `2005` = 2, ...)) `` but there's got to be a better way. I just don't know it, and I couldn't find it. Similar but not the same:  Anyone?

```
year <- c(2003:2017)
random <- c(runif(15))

df = data.frame(year, random)
```

Comment: Just subtract the smallest value: `df$year = df$year - min(df$year)`

Comment: Ah--thanks...I was definitely not thinking the easiest path on that one.